# Converting From .h5 model to .pt model :Convert model from keras h5 to pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tf.keras

How can I use a .h5 model in Pytorch file;
I worked with Keras with TensorFlow backend so here is my saved model:

```
model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights=None, input_tensor=tf.keras.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)), pooling=None)
....#training
model.save("mymodel.h5") 
model.save_weights("saved_weights.h5")
```

Now I migrate to pytorch and I would like to use the saved model. so how can I convert it .
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to try would be to convert the `tensorflow` model to the `ONNX` framework. Then convert the `ONNX` model to `Torch`.

Installing the `tensorflow` to `onnx` converter

```
pip install onnxruntime
pip install git+https://github.com/onnx/tensorflow-onnx
```

converting the `tonsorflow` `saved_model` to `onnx`:

```
python -m tf2onnx.convert --saved-model model_tensorflow --output model.onnx --opset 11 --verbose
```

Converting the `ONNX` to `Pytorch`:

Try using [this repository](https://github.com/ENOT-AutoDL/onnx2torch).